# How can I change the lite mode to dark mode according to the user's time using JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I change the lite mode to dark mode according to the user's time using JS ?

```
// I'm working with jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.toggle').click(function(){

    $('body').toggleClass('dark')
       $('.row1').toggleClass('dark')
       $('.row2').toggleClass('dark')
       $('.row3').toggleClass('dark')
```

i don't have any error

Comment: Question is not clear!

Comment: What have you tried? It should be rather trivial to retrieve the time on the user's machine: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Use `const hour = (new Date).getHours();` to get a value from 0 - 23. Go from there.

Comment: what might be easier as far as toggling the class, rather than toggling the classes on every element, you could use CSS variables. Add the class `light` or `dark` to the outermost wrapper, then use this syntax: `.dark { --main-bg-color: #222 } .light { --main-bg-color: #eee }` and to call that variable: `.body { background: var(--main-bg-color); }` depending on which class the body, or outer-most wrapper, has the content color will change. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, using CSS variables to simplify the js.

```js
$(function() {

  var hour = (new Date).getHours();

  if (hour >= 16) {
    $('.wrapper').removeClass('light').addClass('dark');
  } else {
    $('.wrapper').removeClass('dark').addClass('light');
  }
  console.log(hour);

});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

.light {
  --main-bg-color: #eee;
  --main-tx-color: #000;
}

.dark {
  --main-bg-color: #222;
  --main-tx-color: #555;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--main-bg-color);
}

h2 {
  color: var(--main-tx-color);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper light">
  <h2>SOMETHING HERE</h2>
</div>
```